# HTML table form with multiple inheritance, in cocoon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-table, multiple-inheritance, cocoon-gem

I have a table with cells.

> Using **cocoon** how would I make a form in which each cell `belongs_to` the row, column, and table?

For Example:

```
# Table
class Roster < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :timeslots, inverse_of: :roster
    has_many :games, inverse_of: :roster

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :timeslots, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :games, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

# Column
class Court < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :roster
  has_many :games

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

# Row
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :roster
    has_many :games

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :games, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

# Cell
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :timeslot
    belongs_to :roster
end
```

I am trying now with a hidden `<input>` for each game's `:timeslot_id` and `:court_id` the only problem is you cannot get the id before the timeslot and court is saved. The other idea I ma working on is to for each game to have a hidden `<input>` of the row/column they are in.

Comment: It is maybe easier to use a grid system, like bootstrap offers? But anyway: I see no reason why it should not be possible to use an actual html `table` (it is just harder). So where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think I managed to figure it out. I was doing to much javascript on the front-end than ruby on the back-end. My problem was making each cell belong to the column and row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:
Each cell had two hidden inputs:

```
<%= cell.hidden_field :row %>
<%= cell.hidden_field :column %>
```

The cell `belongs_to` association had to be optional:

```
class Cell < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :table
    belongs_to :column, optional: true
    belongs_to :row, optional: true
end
```

And the Table had an `after_save` callback:

```
after_save do |table|
    table.rows.each_with_index do |row,row_number|
        table.cells.each do |cell|
            if cell.row-1 == row_number
                cell.row = row
                cell.save()
            end
        end
    end
    table.columns.each_with_index do |column,column_number|
        table.cells.each do |cell|
            if cell.column-1 == column_number
                cell.column = column
                cell.save()
            end
        end
    end
end
```

There is probably a better way to do this but I think this is the simplest.
You will need to add an extra two columns to your database: `row` and `column` (The main drawback)